# Handling 404 when updating website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http-status-code-404

I'm (finally) converting my website from classic asp to asp.net MVC. There will be a lot of 404 errors from all the people linking into my website.

What would be the best way to handle this? (show 404 page, automatically redirect to new page, ...)

Also, how will google handle this change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you dont want to lose your current google rank the best choice would be to return 301 status codes and redirect the user to the new url, you can do it using custom routes in your mvc app or IIS url rewriting.